# Swift shorthand to access property versus default value

Tags: swift, option-type

Does Swift have a shorthand syntax for substituting default values when trying to access properties on an optional? For example:

```
let value = anOptional != nil ? anOptional.value : defaultValue
```

This is not a question about the simple use of the ?? coalescing operator, but a question about a shorthand syntax for assigning from a property on a non-nil optional.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this `let value = anOptional ?? defaultValue`

Comment: More in line with the example: `let value = anOptional?.value ?? defaultValue`

Comment: The answer in the comment is actually what I was seeking, not the simple use of the coalescing operator.